# How to detect sentence type using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I want to detect `sentence type`  preferably with python.

For example, given a sentence, the program can detect whether a sentence is a question, or an assertion/statement, or a command etc.

This is different from sentiment/happiness analysis. Is there any tool/new research paper that works reasonably well to do that?

**Note:** I do not have labeled data to train libraries, what I want is a already built model.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data, you can train a classifier algorithm to do that for you. [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/)  is a very simple text processing module for python. It has simple methods like train() that lets you use classification algorithms like Naive Bayes, Decision Trees etc. TextBlob also supports sentiment analysis out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Although [TextBlob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/index.html) doesn't provide exactly this functionality, my intuition will be using TextBlob to parse the corpus (if you have one, or using the [Stanford NLP Corpus](https://nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html)) to create your own `Sentence Type Detector / classifier`.

The basic process maybe:

1. load corpus
2. [tokenise](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#tokenization) the corpus
3. remove [stop words](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dropping-common-terms-stop-words-1.html)
4. [tagging](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#part-of-speech-tagging) part-of-speech
5. extract all the [tone words](https://www.mhasd.k12.wi.us/cms/lib/WI01001388/Centricity/Domain/123/Huge_list_of_tone_words_with_definitions.pdf)
6. calculate the entire sentence type probability based on all the tone words' sentence type probability

Answer (score 0):

You can use NLTK

First it is necessary to isolate the sentences:

```
my_text = "A first affirmation is that Python is useful. But can Python be useful to me?"
from nltk.tokenize    import sent_tokenize
sentences = sent_tokenize(my_text)
print(sentences)
```

Then to check the actual type you can probably need to train a model:

- NLTK or spacy based approach it is easier [NLTK. Detecting whether a sentence is Interrogative or Not in Machine-Learning](https://pyquestions.com/nltk-detecting-whether-a-sentence-is-interrogative-or-not)
- BERT or derivative better accuracy [BERT Text Classification Using Pytorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-text-classification-using-pytorch-723dfb8b6b5b)